# incorrect syntax near ' text data'

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
_dbConnect.ExecuteNonQuery("insert into history(user_id,date,a_id,remark) values('" + lt.Rows[0]["uid"]
        + "','" + DateTime.Now + "','" + ct.Rows[0]["a_id"] + "','" + txtnote.Text + "'");
```

while executing this code "Additional information: Incorrect syntax near 'test entry'." is occurring , the "test entry" is the data i'm entered in txtnote.Text.
please help me to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: change `dbConnect.ExecuteNonQuery` to `print`, and tell us what the printed command looks like

Comment: To know what is wrong with your query, assign your query to a string variable, and then look into it using watch window. This way you'll easily find the issue.  Besides, the way you are making your query, is not a secure way, Always use parametric query.

Comment: Please switch to parameterized queries rather than building queries using string mangling. And, if you do insist on string mangling, one of the quickest diagnostic steps you should take is to *print* the result rather than just executing it, to see if there are any obvious issues with the string that you've constructed.

Comment: In addition to JaydipJ's answer, you should make sure `txtnote.Text` is properly escaped so you'll be safe from SQL injection. Or better yet, use prepared statements. I'm assuming from what you're showing that this is C#. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.prepare.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing closing bracket..
correct statement is...

```
("insert into history(user_id,date,a_id,remark) values('" 
+ lt.Rows[0]["uid"]
+ "','" 
+ DateTime.Now + "','" 
+ ct.Rows[0]["a_id"] + "','" 
+ txtnote.Text 
+ "')");
```